# How to run go generate with executable file in the same folder

Tags: go

I have the executable file in the same folder as where go generate command is written

when I run the command it gives an error

```
 executable file not found in $PATH
```

But I have the executable in the same folder See image below

[image]

Currently I am running

```
go:generate convert
```

How to make go:generate look for binary in the same folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
go:generate ./convert
```

Your executable `convert` is not in your system's path, so you need to give it a relative (as in the above case) or an absolute path for `go generate` or any sub-system to execute it.